# Numerical agreement for 5000 buckets of water

Tags: grammatical-number, measuring-units

5000 buckets of water is removed from a cubical water tank.
or
5000 buckets of water are removed from a cubical water tank.
I think the first one is correct because 'water' is an uncountable noun. Am I right?

Comment: Are you removing the buckets or the water? Presumably the water, because there couldn't have been 5000 actual buckets in the water tank. So for semantic agreement, you need the plural. Which one is "correct"? Probably both; there's no definite rule for this type of thing.

Comment: Peter Shor is asking whether the tank actually contained >5,000 buckets or whether the equivalent of 5,000 water-filled buckets were removed. It's an interesting interpretation,  one that would not have occurred to me, but he's right!

Comment: Five gallons of gas is all you ever need.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Pragmatics _demands_ that the totally wacky interpretation be discounted in standard usage as opposed to logic class. ESU. (I'm sure Peter was being tongue-in-cheek.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Pragmatics aside, it remains a possible interpretation.  And although I was aware it was said with a wink and a twinkle in the eye, that reading would never have occurred me.

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence said "*5000 litres of water ...*" we would know exactly how much water is meant and would have in mind that specific volume rather than its 5000 notional component volumes, acceptably referring to it as a singular (a volume).

However, a *bucket* is not a defined quantity in the same way that *gallons or *litre* are defined. The statement therefore does not equate to a singular volume-equivalent concept; all we know is that 5000 buckets were removed. This means that you should retain the plural usage.

Comment: Are we talking about something that happened with actual buckets or merely a quantity measured in bucketfuls? One is plural and the other is mass.

Comment: 'Bucket' is a fuzzy measure term here, or you'd be taking out 5000 buckets + contents ... compare '24 bottles of water were found in the cellar'. Pragmatics demands that the tank doesn't contain > 4999 pails.

Comment: Five gallons is all you need. Five thousand bucks is more than enough. Buckets, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the arguments that we have already seen, it seems to me that there is no 'correct' answer.  If you follow the rule that the grammatical number of the verb is determined by the grammatical number of it subject, then the verb should be plural, whether the measure be the bucketful or the litre.  If you follow the rule that there is a special exception in the case where, in this case the 'real' subject is the uncountable stuff, water, then, even though that noun is not the grammatical subject, it's number has to determine the number, singular or plural, of the verb.

There is a fair psychological motive for taking this line.  Water is what we are talking about and water is what is being removed.

But consider this:

> Excuse me, Omnifoods, two boxes of chicken has arrived today, when I only ordered one."

This sounds decidedly odd to me, not just because nobody orders just one item from a supermarket.  Chicken, in this case is not countable, since they were not whole chickens).  To some it just be right.  To me it sounds odd.

I want to suggest that we are here on a grammatical grey area.  We have the old singular versus plural dilemma in which the speaker's choice depends on what they see as the true (as opposed to the strictly grammatical) subject of the sentence.

Rules of grammar, after all, are ways of accounting for what speakers and writers of the language are doing or thinking.  They are not forms of legislation.  Except in schoolrooms, of course.

So in answer to the question, I think either will do.

Comment: Two eggs with toast is a fine breakfast.

Comment: @tchrist That is a good example.   I could imagine thinking of them as a (singular) recipe/menu item; but I wouldn't turn a hair at the use of a plural.  Now if you had used the verb 'make', I would start to feel, not uncomfortable exactly, but as if I would in that case think of them as independent co-subjects and so use the plural 'make'.  In fact, I would hear and understand singular or plural without comment.  Unless some teacher had made  point of brainwashing me into one usage or the other!

Comment: I can't accept the plural verb. This **must** be referring (inexactly) to a volume of water, not a physical 5000 buckets, each filled with water, pre-existing in the water tank. [Cambridge.Org.Grammar...](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/grammar-practice-activities/2015/12/compound-quantifiers-alternatives-to-much-and-many) includes '[a] bucket of' as a compound quantifier. Compare 'Shedloads of wood has been destroyed'; '10 teaspoonsful is all you need'.